# How to save cookies in jmeter recording and replay

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies, recording

Here i have two questions regarding capturing the cookies through JMeter. I am using JMeter recording to capture the web browser flow . And i have added Cookies Manager under the Test plan (common for all requests) Below is my flow :

> launch >select Providers >sign-In

While recording it is capturing the cookies properly . i am able to see in the "Request Data" in "View Results Tree" . But while trying to replay i am not seeing the cookies in the results.
Please let me know if i am missing some settings here.

How this will work when we increase the no of users and run.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter doesn't record cookies, if you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan it will automatically extract the cookies from the application's [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header, parse them, validate and send with [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header during the next request.

If you cannot see any cookies the reasons could be in:

1. Cookies are invalid (i.e. expired, not matching the domain/path)
2. Your test fails somewhere somehow, i.e. your sign-in request fails because you haven't implemented [correlation of the dynamic parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)

Inspect response details using "Response Data" tab of the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing as it looks like it doesn't go further than first page in your case